# Fetch QrCode SVG from API using axios and show it in a div in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have an API that returns a SVG response after i call it. The SVG that is returned from API has below format(it is rendered):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="#ffffff"/><g transform="scale(6.897)"><g transform="translate(0,0)"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9 0L9 1L10 1L10 2L8 2L8 3L9 3L9 4L10 4L10 5L9 5L9 6L8 6L8 8L4 8L4 9L3 9L3 8L0 8L0 9L3 9L3 10L2 10L2 12L0 12L0 14L1 14L1 13L2 13L2 12L3 12L3 11L4 11L4 9L8 9L8 10L5 10L5 11L8 11L8 12L6 12L6 13L8 13L8 17L7 17L7 16L6 16L6 15L7 15L7 14L6 14L6 15L5 15L5 12L4 12L4 13L3 13L3 14L2 14L2 15L0 15L0 16L1 16L1 18L0 18L0 19L1 19L1 20L0 20L0 21L1 21L1 20L2 20L2 19L3 19L3 20L4 20L4 19L5 19L5 20L6 20L6 21L7 21L7 20L8 20L8 25L9 25L9 26L8 26L8 29L9 29L9 27L10 27L10 29L11 29L11 28L12 28L12 29L13 29L13 28L12 28L12 27L11 27L11 26L12 26L12 24L14 24L14 25L15 25L15 24L16 24L16 23L17 23L17 25L16 25L16 27L17 27L17 29L18 29L18 27L19 27L19 29L22 29L22 28L24 28L24 27L27 27L27 29L29 29L29 28L28 28L28 27L29 27L29 25L26 25L26 22L25 22L25 21L26 21L26 19L27 19L27 20L28 20L28 21L27 21L27 24L29 24L29 12L28 12L28 17L26 17L26 19L25 19L25 18L23 18L23 16L22 16L22 14L23 14L23 15L24 15L24 12L22 12L22 11L29 11L29 9L28 9L28 10L26 10L26 9L27 9L27 8L26 8L26 9L25 9L25 10L24 10L24 9L23 9L23 8L21 8L21 6L20 6L20 3L19 3L19 2L20 2L20 1L21 1L21 0L19 0L19 1L17 1L17 2L18 2L18 4L19 4L19 6L18 6L18 5L17 5L17 6L16 6L16 4L15 4L15 3L16 3L16 0L14 0L14 2L15 2L15 3L14 3L14 4L15 4L15 6L14 6L14 7L13 7L13 6L12 6L12 8L11 8L11 6L10 6L10 5L11 5L11 4L12 4L12 3L13 3L13 0L12 0L12 1L10 1L10 0ZM11 2L11 3L12 3L12 2ZM9 6L9 7L10 7L10 6ZM15 6L15 8L14 8L14 9L13 9L13 8L12 8L12 10L10 10L10 8L9 8L9 10L10 10L10 11L9 11L9 12L8 12L8 13L10 13L10 14L9 14L9 16L10 16L10 14L11 14L11 13L12 13L12 12L13 12L13 11L14 11L14 13L13 13L13 14L14 14L14 17L13 17L13 16L12 16L12 15L11 15L11 16L12 16L12 18L11 18L11 17L8 17L8 19L9 19L9 22L10 22L10 20L11 20L11 21L12 21L12 20L13 20L13 19L14 19L14 21L15 21L15 23L14 23L14 22L13 22L13 23L14 23L14 24L15 24L15 23L16 23L16 21L17 21L17 23L18 23L18 21L19 21L19 22L20 22L20 20L21 20L21 19L22 19L22 20L24 20L24 19L22 19L22 16L21 16L21 18L20 18L20 17L19 17L19 16L18 16L18 17L17 17L17 19L16 19L16 16L15 16L15 15L16 15L16 14L17 14L17 11L20 11L20 13L19 13L19 12L18 12L18 13L19 13L19 14L18 14L18 15L21 15L21 11L22 11L22 9L21 9L21 8L18 8L18 10L17 10L17 11L16 11L16 9L15 9L15 8L17 8L17 7L18 7L18 6L17 6L17 7L16 7L16 6ZM19 6L19 7L20 7L20 6ZM14 9L14 11L15 11L15 9ZM0 10L0 11L1 11L1 10ZM11 11L11 12L12 12L12 11ZM25 13L25 14L26 14L26 15L27 15L27 13ZM3 14L3 15L4 15L4 14ZM2 16L2 18L1 18L1 19L2 19L2 18L3 18L3 19L4 19L4 18L7 18L7 17L4 17L4 18L3 18L3 16ZM18 17L18 19L17 19L17 21L18 21L18 19L19 19L19 17ZM9 18L9 19L11 19L11 20L12 20L12 19L11 19L11 18ZM14 18L14 19L15 19L15 21L16 21L16 19L15 19L15 18ZM6 19L6 20L7 20L7 19ZM21 21L21 24L24 24L24 21ZM22 22L22 23L23 23L23 22ZM9 23L9 25L10 25L10 26L11 26L11 25L10 25L10 23ZM11 23L11 24L12 24L12 23ZM18 24L18 25L17 25L17 27L18 27L18 26L19 26L19 25L20 25L20 26L21 26L21 27L23 27L23 25L20 25L20 24ZM13 26L13 27L14 27L14 26ZM27 26L27 27L28 27L28 26ZM15 28L15 29L16 29L16 28ZM25 28L25 29L26 29L26 28ZM0 0L0 7L7 7L7 0ZM1 1L1 6L6 6L6 1ZM2 2L2 5L5 5L5 2ZM22 0L22 7L29 7L29 0ZM23 1L23 6L28 6L28 1ZM24 2L24 5L27 5L27 2ZM0 22L0 29L7 29L7 22ZM1 23L1 28L6 28L6 23ZM2 24L2 27L5 27L5 24Z" fill="#000000"/></g></g></svg>
```

How can i show it in a div? I've tried two things so far

```
first
<div>
   <img src={wallet.QrCode} />
</div>
```

```
second
<div>
    {wallet.QrCode}
</div>
```

The first one shows nothing and second one shows it as a text.

Comment: please add the value of `wallet.QrCoe`

Comment: It is the same as what the API returns. I wrote it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render the `svg` without the first line, for example:

```html
      <div>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          version="1.1"
          width="200"
          height="200"
          viewBox="0 0 200 200"
        >
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="#ffffff" />
          <g transform="scale(6.897)">
            <g transform="translate(0,0)">
              <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                d="M9 0L9 1L10 1L10 2L8 2L8 3L9 3L9 4L10 4L10 5L9 5L9 6L8 6L8 8L4 8L4 9L3 9L3 8L0 8L0 9L3 9L3 10L2 10L2 12L0 12L0 14L1 14L1 13L2 13L2 12L3 12L3 11L4 11L4 9L8 9L8 10L5 10L5 11L8 11L8 12L6 12L6 13L8 13L8 17L7 17L7 16L6 16L6 15L7 15L7 14L6 14L6 15L5 15L5 12L4 12L4 13L3 13L3 14L2 14L2 15L0 15L0 16L1 16L1 18L0 18L0 19L1 19L1 20L0 20L0 21L1 21L1 20L2 20L2 19L3 19L3 20L4 20L4 19L5 19L5 20L6 20L6 21L7 21L7 20L8 20L8 25L9 25L9 26L8 26L8 29L9 29L9 27L10 27L10 29L11 29L11 28L12 28L12 29L13 29L13 28L12 28L12 27L11 27L11 26L12 26L12 24L14 24L14 25L15 25L15 24L16 24L16 23L17 23L17 25L16 25L16 27L17 27L17 29L18 29L18 27L19 27L19 29L22 29L22 28L24 28L24 27L27 27L27 29L29 29L29 28L28 28L28 27L29 27L29 25L26 25L26 22L25 22L25 21L26 21L26 19L27 19L27 20L28 20L28 21L27 21L27 24L29 24L29 12L28 12L28 17L26 17L26 19L25 19L25 18L23 18L23 16L22 16L22 14L23 14L23 15L24 15L24 12L22 12L22 11L29 11L29 9L28 9L28 10L26 10L26 9L27 9L27 8L26 8L26 9L25 9L25 10L24 10L24 9L23 9L23 8L21 8L21 6L20 6L20 3L19 3L19 2L20 2L20 1L21 1L21 0L19 0L19 1L17 1L17 2L18 2L18 4L19 4L19 6L18 6L18 5L17 5L17 6L16 6L16 4L15 4L15 3L16 3L16 0L14 0L14 2L15 2L15 3L14 3L14 4L15 4L15 6L14 6L14 7L13 7L13 6L12 6L12 8L11 8L11 6L10 6L10 5L11 5L11 4L12 4L12 3L13 3L13 0L12 0L12 1L10 1L10 0ZM11 2L11 3L12 3L12 2ZM9 6L9 7L10 7L10 6ZM15 6L15 8L14 8L14 9L13 9L13 8L12 8L12 10L10 10L10 8L9 8L9 10L10 10L10 11L9 11L9 12L8 12L8 13L10 13L10 14L9 14L9 16L10 16L10 14L11 14L11 13L12 13L12 12L13 12L13 11L14 11L14 13L13 13L13 14L14 14L14 17L13 17L13 16L12 16L12 15L11 15L11 16L12 16L12 18L11 18L11 17L8 17L8 19L9 19L9 22L10 22L10 20L11 20L11 21L12 21L12 20L13 20L13 19L14 19L14 21L15 21L15 23L14 23L14 22L13 22L13 23L14 23L14 24L15 24L15 23L16 23L16 21L17 21L17 23L18 23L18 21L19 21L19 22L20 22L20 20L21 20L21 19L22 19L22 20L24 20L24 19L22 19L22 16L21 16L21 18L20 18L20 17L19 17L19 16L18 16L18 17L17 17L17 19L16 19L16 16L15 16L15 15L16 15L16 14L17 14L17 11L20 11L20 13L19 13L19 12L18 12L18 13L19 13L19 14L18 14L18 15L21 15L21 11L22 11L22 9L21 9L21 8L18 8L18 10L17 10L17 11L16 11L16 9L15 9L15 8L17 8L17 7L18 7L18 6L17 6L17 7L16 7L16 6ZM19 6L19 7L20 7L20 6ZM14 9L14 11L15 11L15 9ZM0 10L0 11L1 11L1 10ZM11 11L11 12L12 12L12 11ZM25 13L25 14L26 14L26 15L27 15L27 13ZM3 14L3 15L4 15L4 14ZM2 16L2 18L1 18L1 19L2 19L2 18L3 18L3 19L4 19L4 18L7 18L7 17L4 17L4 18L3 18L3 16ZM18 17L18 19L17 19L17 21L18 21L18 19L19 19L19 17ZM9 18L9 19L11 19L11 20L12 20L12 19L11 19L11 18ZM14 18L14 19L15 19L15 21L16 21L16 19L15 19L15 18ZM6 19L6 20L7 20L7 19ZM21 21L21 24L24 24L24 21ZM22 22L22 23L23 23L23 22ZM9 23L9 25L10 25L10 26L11 26L11 25L10 25L10 23ZM11 23L11 24L12 24L12 23ZM18 24L18 25L17 25L17 27L18 27L18 26L19 26L19 25L20 25L20 26L21 26L21 27L23 27L23 25L20 25L20 24ZM13 26L13 27L14 27L14 26ZM27 26L27 27L28 27L28 26ZM15 28L15 29L16 29L16 28ZM25 28L25 29L26 29L26 28ZM0 0L0 7L7 7L7 0ZM1 1L1 6L6 6L6 1ZM2 2L2 5L5 5L5 2ZM22 0L22 7L29 7L29 0ZM23 1L23 6L28 6L28 1ZM24 2L24 5L27 5L27 2ZM0 22L0 29L7 29L7 22ZM1 23L1 28L6 28L6 23ZM2 24L2 27L5 27L5 24Z"
                fill="#000000"
              />
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
```

Edit:
You can use a base64 string, here is a full implementation:

```
export const App = () => {
  const wallet = {
    QrCode: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="#ffffff"/><g transform="scale(6.897)"><g transform="translate(0,0)"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9 0L9 1L10 1L10 2L8 2L8 3L9 3L9 4L10 4L10 5L9 5L9 6L8 6L8 8L4 8L4 9L3 9L3 8L0 8L0 9L3 9L3 10L2 10L2 12L0 12L0 14L1 14L1 13L2 13L2 12L3 12L3 11L4 11L4 9L8 9L8 10L5 10L5 11L8 11L8 12L6 12L6 13L8 13L8 17L7 17L7 16L6 16L6 15L7 15L7 14L6 14L6 15L5 15L5 12L4 12L4 13L3 13L3 14L2 14L2 15L0 15L0 16L1 16L1 18L0 18L0 19L1 19L1 20L0 20L0 21L1 21L1 20L2 20L2 19L3 19L3 20L4 20L4 19L5 19L5 20L6 20L6 21L7 21L7 20L8 20L8 25L9 25L9 26L8 26L8 29L9 29L9 27L10 27L10 29L11 29L11 28L12 28L12 29L13 29L13 28L12 28L12 27L11 27L11 26L12 26L12 24L14 24L14 25L15 25L15 24L16 24L16 23L17 23L17 25L16 25L16 27L17 27L17 29L18 29L18 27L19 27L19 29L22 29L22 28L24 28L24 27L27 27L27 29L29 29L29 28L28 28L28 27L29 27L29 25L26 25L26 22L25 22L25 21L26 21L26 19L27 19L27 20L28 20L28 21L27 21L27 24L29 24L29 12L28 12L28 17L26 17L26 19L25 19L25 18L23 18L23 16L22 16L22 14L23 14L23 15L24 15L24 12L22 12L22 11L29 11L29 9L28 9L28 10L26 10L26 9L27 9L27 8L26 8L26 9L25 9L25 10L24 10L24 9L23 9L23 8L21 8L21 6L20 6L20 3L19 3L19 2L20 2L20 1L21 1L21 0L19 0L19 1L17 1L17 2L18 2L18 4L19 4L19 6L18 6L18 5L17 5L17 6L16 6L16 4L15 4L15 3L16 3L16 0L14 0L14 2L15 2L15 3L14 3L14 4L15 4L15 6L14 6L14 7L13 7L13 6L12 6L12 8L11 8L11 6L10 6L10 5L11 5L11 4L12 4L12 3L13 3L13 0L12 0L12 1L10 1L10 0ZM11 2L11 3L12 3L12 2ZM9 6L9 7L10 7L10 6ZM15 6L15 8L14 8L14 9L13 9L13 8L12 8L12 10L10 10L10 8L9 8L9 10L10 10L10 11L9 11L9 12L8 12L8 13L10 13L10 14L9 14L9 16L10 16L10 14L11 14L11 13L12 13L12 12L13 12L13 11L14 11L14 13L13 13L13 14L14 14L14 17L13 17L13 16L12 16L12 15L11 15L11 16L12 16L12 18L11 18L11 17L8 17L8 19L9 19L9 22L10 22L10 20L11 20L11 21L12 21L12 20L13 20L13 19L14 19L14 21L15 21L15 23L14 23L14 22L13 22L13 23L14 23L14 24L15 24L15 23L16 23L16 21L17 21L17 23L18 23L18 21L19 21L19 22L20 22L20 20L21 20L21 19L22 19L22 20L24 20L24 19L22 19L22 16L21 16L21 18L20 18L20 17L19 17L19 16L18 16L18 17L17 17L17 19L16 19L16 16L15 16L15 15L16 15L16 14L17 14L17 11L20 11L20 13L19 13L19 12L18 12L18 13L19 13L19 14L18 14L18 15L21 15L21 11L22 11L22 9L21 9L21 8L18 8L18 10L17 10L17 11L16 11L16 9L15 9L15 8L17 8L17 7L18 7L18 6L17 6L17 7L16 7L16 6ZM19 6L19 7L20 7L20 6ZM14 9L14 11L15 11L15 9ZM0 10L0 11L1 11L1 10ZM11 11L11 12L12 12L12 11ZM25 13L25 14L26 14L26 15L27 15L27 13ZM3 14L3 15L4 15L4 14ZM2 16L2 18L1 18L1 19L2 19L2 18L3 18L3 19L4 19L4 18L7 18L7 17L4 17L4 18L3 18L3 16ZM18 17L18 19L17 19L17 21L18 21L18 19L19 19L19 17ZM9 18L9 19L11 19L11 20L12 20L12 19L11 19L11 18ZM14 18L14 19L15 19L15 21L16 21L16 19L15 19L15 18ZM6 19L6 20L7 20L7 19ZM21 21L21 24L24 24L24 21ZM22 22L22 23L23 23L23 22ZM9 23L9 25L10 25L10 26L11 26L11 25L10 25L10 23ZM11 23L11 24L12 24L12 23ZM18 24L18 25L17 25L17 27L18 27L18 26L19 26L19 25L20 25L20 26L21 26L21 27L23 27L23 25L20 25L20 24ZM13 26L13 27L14 27L14 26ZM27 26L27 27L28 27L28 26ZM15 28L15 29L16 29L16 28ZM25 28L25 29L26 29L26 28ZM0 0L0 7L7 7L7 0ZM1 1L1 6L6 6L6 1ZM2 2L2 5L5 5L5 2ZM22 0L22 7L29 7L29 0ZM23 1L23 6L28 6L28 1ZM24 2L24 5L27 5L27 2ZM0 22L0 29L7 29L7 22ZM1 23L1 28L6 28L6 23ZM2 24L2 27L5 27L5 24Z" fill="#000000"/></g></g></svg>`,
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={`data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(wallet.QrCode)}`} alt="" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i want to connect it to the state of my program. That's why i used `wallet.QrCode`

Comment: @ArdalanNahavandi Take a look at the edit please.

Comment: Thanks a loootttt man you saved me the day